# File not getting created in .bat via c# code

Tags: batch-file, c#-3.0

I have created a c# program and a .bat file.My simple objective is to pass an parameter to the bacth file and run it.I can pass the parameter and scho it in batch file but I am not able to create any log file.
I tried a lot but no success.this is first attemp to mix c# and batch programing(not good at batch).here is the code.

```
class Class2
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string MyBatchFile = "C:\Users\Documents\FileWatcherDocuments\Test.bat";
        string testdata = "watcherprogram";


        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                Arguments = String.Format("{0}", testdata) 
            }
        };
        process.StartInfo.FileName = MyBatchFile;
        bool b = process.Start();
        }
        }
    }
```

and my Test.bat has simple code.

```
    echo The filename should be passed as a cmd line arg %1 >> fileWatcherOutput.log
```

The Output is

```
    The filename should be passed as a cmd line arg watcherprogram.
```

BUT the file "filewatcherOutput.log" is not getting created.It is created when i am executing it from command prompt but not by C#.

Any help will be appeciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah...got it.
I dont know why but changing my batch file and giving full file path did my job.

Changed my batch file to. 
echo The filename should be passed as a cmd line arg %1      >>C:\Users\Documents\FileWatcherDocuments\fileWatcherOutput.log

pause